# python numpy detect and eliminate undesired value

Tags: python, numpy

I have a (x;y) set of points in Numpy array, that represent the curve which showed below. I want to detect and eliminate the value in the array that that broke the continuity of the function. Is it possible to do that?

[image]

**EDIT**
Here's is a set of data values of the function where the non desirable value is located. I located manually but this is not what I need

```
set_of_data = np.array([
     [ 0.01099914,  0.1990088 ],
     [ 0.00235953,  0.20015288],
     [-0.00628651,  0.20127308],
     [-0.01493928,  0.20236874],
     [-0.02359911,  0.20343921],
     [-0.0322663,   0.20448377],
     [-0.04094121,  0.20550169],
     [-0.04962419,  0.20649219],
     [-0.0583156,   0.20745447],
     [-0.06701583,  0.20838767],
     [-0.07572529,  0.20929091],
     [-0.0844444,   0.21016325],
     [-0.09317361,  0.21100373],
     [-0.10191339,  0.2118113 ],
     [-0.11066424,  0.21258489],
     [-0.11942668,  0.21332338],
     [-0.12820128,  0.21402557],
     [-0.13698863,  0.2146902 ],
     [-0.10507277,  0.20535413],   #<-- point to remove
     [-0.14749565,  0.21590372],
     [-0.15646386,  0.2164481 ],
     [-0.16552084,  0.21694332],
     [-0.17466738,  0.2173836 ],
     [-0.18390426,  0.21776298],
     [-0.19323216,  0.21807525],
     [-0.20265175,  0.21831395],
     [-0.21216362,  0.21847237],
     [-0.2217683,  0.21854352],
     [-0.23146627,  0.21852011],
     [-0.24125792,  0.21839456]
 ])
```

Comment: It would help to see the values of the dataset.

Comment: @Falko I update my question

Comment: There are many values missing. To get a really useful answer, you should post all your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a rather robust approach:

```
for i in range(1, len(data) - 1):
    backward_angle = np.arctan2(data[i][1] - data[i - 1][1], data[i][0] - data[i - 1][0])
    forward_angle = np.arctan2(data[i + 1][1] - data[i][1], data[i + 1][0] - data[i][0])
    angle_difference = (backward_angle - forward_angle + np.pi) % (2 * np.pi) - np.pi
    if np.absolute(angle_difference) > np.pi / 2:
        print "Outlier:", data[i]
```

It computes the direction from the previous point to the current one and from the current one to the next point. If the difference (modulo 2 pi) is larger then pi/2 (i.e. 90 degrees), an outlier is detected.

Output:

```
Outlier: [-0.13698863  0.2146902 ]
Outlier: [-0.10507277  0.20535413]
```

Note that two points are detected, since there are two changes in direction.

Answer (score 3):

How about you loop through the inner rows, checking to see that x[i] is inbetween x[i-1] and x[i+1]; also check that y[i] is inbetween y[i-1] and y[i+1].

You would need to check both the case of

z[i-1] < z[i] < z[i+1]
and 
z[i+1] < z[i] < z[i-1]

If both of these are false, then delete the point.

Comment: This does not work with the very left point. It's not included in the coordinate list, however.

Comment: How about if you split the data into curves that pass the vertical line test?